# jquery - Can I retrieve (event, xhr, options) from .ajaxStart or .ajaxStop?

Tags: jquery

Based on http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

```
.ajaxComplete( handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) )
.ajaxStart( handler(event) )
```

To my knowledge and experiements, the XMLHttpRequest and ajaxOptions parameters for the handler of .ajaxStart or .ajaxStop are null.

I would like to retrieve the ajaxOptions information inside the functions of .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop. Is that possible?

What problems will I have if I hook up with .ajaxSend + .ajaxComplete rather than .ajaxStart + .ajaxComplete. The major reason I like to do so is that .ajaxSend can access all three parameters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't access them here because these events are for when the active count of requests changes to above 0 and back, but aren't *per-request*, they're for overall activity.

I think what you're after is [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) which fire per-request and have the requested parameters, for example:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
  //do start stuff
}).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
  //do end stuff
});
```