# Prevent ajax load animation in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have global ajax load animation that runs in every ajax called. But in this case, I want to disable that effect. How can I do that?

This is for global animation :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $('#ajax-loader').show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
   $('#ajax-loader').fadeOut(200);
});
```

And below the code that I won't to show the animation.

```
setInterval(function(){
   chat_notif(); //function that contain an ajax call
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a global boolean variable `showAjaxAnimation` with default value `true`. In the `setInterval` you could make something like that.

```
setInterval(function(){
   showAjaxAnimation = false;
   chat_notif(); //function that contain an ajax call
   showAjaxAnimation = true;
}, 1000);
```

And then in the `AjaxStart` you could do:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   if (showAjaxAnimation)
     $('#ajax-loader').show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
   $('#ajax-loader').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate by checking the `xhr` or `options` from the `ajaxSend()`

```
var ajaxXhr, ajaxOptions;
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
   ajaxXhr = xhr;
   ajaxOptions = options;
}).ajaxStart(function(){
   if(ajaxXhr || ajaxOptions ) //something that detects the specific case
    $('#ajax-loader').show();
};
```

[jquery - Can I retrieve (event, xhr, options) from .ajaxStart or .ajaxStop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497229/jquery-can-i-retrieve-event-xhr-options-from-ajaxstart-or-ajaxstop)

**Usage:**

Lets say you want to go for the url `"/rest/refreshChatNotifications"`, this url will be within the `XHR` or `options` (i guess in xhr). Now you can use the `if` within the `ajaxStart` to check against this url.

```
var ajaxXhr, ajaxOptions, refreshChatUrl = "/rest/refreshChatNotifications";
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
   ajaxXhr = xhr;
   ajaxOptions = options;
}).ajaxStart(function(){
   if(ajaxXhr.url !=  refreshChatUrl ) //if it's the specific url, dont show
    $('#ajax-loader').show();
};
```

if you have **multiple urls**, that shouldn't show animations, do it like this:

```
var ajaxXhr, ajaxOptions;
var dontShowAnimationForUrls = ["/rest/refreshChatNotifications", "/rest/anotherAjaxWithoutLoader"];
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
   ajaxXhr = xhr;
   ajaxOptions = options;
}).ajaxStart(function(){
   if(dontShowAnimationForUrls.indexOf(ajaxXhr.url) < -1) //if it's the specific url, dont show. Index will be > -1, then url found.
    $('#ajax-loader').show();
};
```